# Loopback "hasManyThrough" relation. Where to add it?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a User entity and a Hobbie entity, both have their models defined in Loopback and I see them in the API explorer.

I have a table UserHobbie that links User and Hobbie in a ManyToMany relation. I'm tryting to declare a loopback [hasManyThrough](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/HasManyThrough+relations) relation such as

```
User.hasMany(Hobbie, {through: UserHobbie});
```

but I cannot seem to do it well, for **it doesn't show up in the explorer**. I've declared it in `/server/server.js` right after the bootstrapping section, and I've tried doing it in `/common/User.js` and `/common/Hobbie.js` (but in either one of them, the other model isn't visible).

Is there a proper syntax to add this in User.json or Hobbie.json? That would be my preferred way to go, since anything I put in the json definition shows up right in the explorer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve the problem within your Model JSON, I'll outline the Solution below.  However, using a "hasAndBelongsToMany" Relationship would solve your problem more simply and I'll outline that below also.

Within your User.json:

```
  "relations": {
    "Hobbies": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Hobbie",
      "through": "UserHobbie",
      "foreignKey": "hobbieId"
    }
  }
```

Within your Hobbie.json:

```
  "relations": {
    "Users": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "User",
      "through": "UserHobbie",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  }
```

Your UserHobbie.json would look like this (note that you DO NOT define userId OR hobbieId within "properties":

```
{
  "name": "UserHobbie",
  "plural": "UserHobbies",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "String",
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "Users": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "User",
        "foreignKey": "userId"
    },
    "Hobbies": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "Hobbie",
        "foreignKey": "hobbieId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

THIS SIMPLER WAY TO DO THIS IS BELOW:

DON'T EXPLICITLY CREATE A UserHobbies Model.  Loopback will AUTOMATICALLY create a Join Model for you.

Within your User Model:

```
  "relations": {
    "Hobbies": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Hobbie"
    }
  }
```

Within you Hobbie Model:

```
  "relations": {
    "Users": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "User"
    }
  }
```

If you want to do this in code, YOU ARE CORRECT, there are Bootstrap Timing Issues that keep these Relationships from appearing in Explorer.   I will add another response soon to show you how to make that work too.

Comment: Thank you! Are you related in some way to StrongLoop? Because, in that case, I'd beg that you add that answer to the documentation in the [hasManyThrough](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/HasManyThrough+relations) and [hasAndBelongToMany](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations) sections, which doesn't have the json analogy to the code definition of those relations.

Comment: We will be doing that soon...   That's code/JSON examples problem is common and we'll be working on it...  Thanks for allowing me to get you past this...

Comment: Dear @tonyStrong, if I go through the second solution... and I don't have a hobbieId in Users, nor a userId in Hobbies... how could loopback automatically create a join model?

Comment: Another quick one: why do you explicitly say NOT TO include FKs in the join model definition?

Comment: Because, for hasAndBelongsToMany Relationships, it will automatically use the Model Names to generate the foreign keys and they are descriptive.

Comment: @tonyStrong more than a year later and the example still isn't in the Loopback docs :)  but this SO answer really helped me a lot - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Now, to make your original Code Based Implementation of creating Relationships show up in Explorer, here is what you should do.

First, from your Loopback Projects's ./server/boot directory, move "explorer.js" to ./server (where server.js is in the project.

The last portion of ./server/server.js should look something like this (I've eliminated some comments for brevity.

```
boot(app, __dirname);

... // Removed for brevity

app.use(loopback.urlNotFound());

// The ultimate error handler.
app.use(loopback.errorHandler());

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
  });
};

// start the server if `$ node server.js`
if (require.main === module) {
  app.start();
}
```

Now EDIT the last part of .server/server.js to look like this:

```
boot(app, __dirname);
    // We took explorer.js out of /boot and put it in /server root next to server.js


var programmaticLoopbackSetup = require('./programmaticLoopbackSetup');
    // If the User has any special Programmatic Loopback Setup (create Model Relationships, etc.) do it first

if (programmaticLoopbackSetup !== undefined) {
    programmaticLoopbackSetup(app, finishUp);
}
else {
    finishUp();  // If you didn't want any Code based Setup
}

// Defer all the rest of the Startup Work until Explorer 
// has all the Model Info it needs from any Async or Programmatic Setup.
function finishUp() {

    require('./explorer')(app);
        // This was formerly done within "boot" above...

        ...  // removed for brevity...

    // Requests that get this far won't be handled
    // by any middleware. Convert them into a 404 error
    // that will be handled later down the chain.
    app.use(loopback.urlNotFound());

    // The ultimate error handler.
    app.use(loopback.errorHandler());

    app.start = function() {
      // start the web server
      return app.listen(function() {
        app.emit('started');
        console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
      });
    };

    // start the server if `$ node server.js`
    if (require.main === module) {
      app.start();
    }
}
```

Add a new file at ./server/programmaticLoopbackSetup.js and make it look something like below (notice how it is called after "boot" and before finalizing the App Initialization

```
module.exports = function programmaticLoopbackSetup(app, next) {
    var User = app.models.User;
    var Hobbie = app.models.Hobbie;


    // This Block Below Creates a Many to Many User / Hobbie Relationship directly 

        User.hasAndBelongsToMany(Hobbie);
        Hobbie.hasAndBelongsToMany(User);

    next();  // Callback to finish App Init...
};
```

You will see the User / Hobbie Relationships (using "hasAndBelongsToMany" in this case) within Explorer.  Do WHATEVER Code Based LoopBack Model, Datasource, or other refinements within programmaticLoopbackSetup.js

Comment: Thank you. I believe I can cope with the method not showing up in the explorer, as long as it works in commandline.